# Counting letters by comparing string to array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, reference

I'm working on a function that takes user input as a reference from main, and compares it to a string array where the alphabet is stored. My goal is to make the function count the number of times each letter is present in the user_string. Here is what i got so far:

```
int letter_counter(string user_Text_Ref)
{
    string alfa_arr[LETTERS] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    int antal_arr[LETTERS] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < sizeof(user_Text_Ref) ; j++)
        {
            if(alfa_arr[i] == user_Text_Ref(j)) // Here is my problem.
            {
                antal_arr[i] += 1;
                cout << alfa_arr[i] << " : " << antal_arr[i] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
return antal_arr;
}
```

so to quickly sum up what this is. The function letter_counter takes a reference to a user submitted string from main as an argument.
LETTERS is a const int set to 26.
alfa_arr contains all the lowercase letters a-z and the antal_arr contains 
numbers corresponding to the letters, for keeping count of occurences of all 
the letters. 
The first for loop iterates trough all the letters and second one iterates trough the string user_Text_Ref and it's right there that i'm confused.

I've tried several ways of comparing alfa_arr[i] with user_Text_Ref (==,strcmp and variations of these and a few i don't remember)
I get an error that I don't understand (I'm using codeblocks) :

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (int&)’|
```

*what does this mean ?*

*what is the best way of comparing the two strings in this situation ?*

(*can you make a multidimensional array with both strings and ints ?* )

I am still fairly new to c++, any help or advice is appreciated.
Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Cheers!

Comment: you would probably prefer `int antal_arr[LETTERS] = {};` to zero initialize

Comment: You can get the ith char of a `string` with `user_Text_Ref[j]`

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)`?

Comment: [Maps](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) would be a better choice to store alphabets as keys and number of occurences as value

Comment: To explain @LogicStuff comment, you get the size of a `std::string ` instance with `user_Text_Ref.size()`

Comment: @Voidchar And please, define your loop control variables `i` and `j` inside the for-loop construct.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis But wont that just reference whatever is in the memory at that particular address ?

Comment: `user_Text_Ref` is a `std::string` object that you pass to the function by value (copying). `size()` member function and `[]` operator are both called on that object. You probably want to pass strings by reference : `int letter_counter(const string &user_Text_Ref)`

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are trying to use the string as a function. To get a single character from it use `[]`, not `()`. That way you are indexing individual characters in the string.

```
if(alfa_arr[i] == user_Text_Ref[j])
```

Secondly, you have an array of strings for the characters in `alfa-arr`. You most likely want to store single chars there and compare to those to the characters iterated from the string.

```
char alfa_arr[LETTERS] = { 'a', 'b', ... };
```

Thirdly, to get the length of the string use `user_Text_Ref.length()`, `sizeof` will only give you the size of the memory allocated for that object in this case.

Comment: This answer cleared it all up. Thank you Sami! I really appreciate the guidance. 
Now i understand why it threw an error when i tried setting alfa_arr as a char. since i was using double quotes it, it treated it as a string literal with a character and a null-terminator. I changed it to single quotes and that made it work. Now i just have to figure out the correct way to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
user_Text_Ref[j]
```

Also note that you can find out the number of a letter by simply subtracting `'a'` from that letter:

```
for(j = 0;j < user_Text_Ref.length(); j++) { // sizeof is also a problem here
    if (user_Text_Ref[j]>='a' && user_Text_Ref[j]<='z') { // if this is a letter
        pos =  user_Text_Ref[j] - 'a'; // find its number but sbtracting 'a' code from its code
        antal_arr[pos] ++;
        cout << user_Text_Ref[j] << " : " << antal_arr[pos] << endl;
    }
}
```

so you do not need `alfa_arr` array at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your aim using this code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int LETTERS = 26;

void letter_counter(string str, int* p) {

    // fill up alphabet array
    char alfa_arr[LETTERS] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++) {
        alfa_arr[i] = static_cast<char>(i + 97);
    }

    // convert string to lowercase
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);

    // fill up occurrences array
    for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++) {
        *p++ = count(str.begin(), str.end(), alfa_arr[i]);
    }
}

int main() {

    int antal_arr[LETTERS] = { 0 };
    int* p = nullptr;
    string str{"This program counts letter OCCURRENCES in TEXT despite CASE"};  

    // fill occurrences array
    p = &antal_arr[0];
    letter_counter(str, p);

    // show results
    for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++) {
        cout << antal_arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that **letter_counter** does not return type int. Instead, it populates an array of int that is external to it.